# PHP local array in function?

Tags: php, arrays, function, local

I have a game that will display ten random cards based on number and suit, but I need to check an array to see if the card has already been displayed. But my local array `$card` is not being saved when it passes through the function. Here is all my code for right now please try running it and tell me what I am doing wrong if you want the images they are avaiable at.

http://storealutes.com/blackjack/cards.zip

here is my php:

```
    <?php
                                     //suit 1=Clubs | 2=Hearts | 3=Spades | 4=Diamonds//
                                     //Color 1=1or11 | 2-10=#   | 11-12=10//
$number;
$suit;
$card = array();

function newcard($number,$suit,$card){

$arrsuit = array (clubs, hearts, spades, diamonds);
$arrnumber = array (a, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, j, q, k);

$number = $arrnumber[rand(0,12)];                //Creates card value
$suit   = $arrsuit[rand(0,3)];       //Create card suit
$card   .= array  ($suit ." ". $number, hello);       //difines card name
return "<img src='cards/" . $suit . "-" . $number . "-150.png'/>";
}
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
echo newcard($number,$suit,$card);
}
echo $number;
foreach($card as $value){
    echo $value;
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a variable inside of a function use the follow techniques.

```
$GLOBALS['card'][] = array  ($suit ." ". $number, hello);
```

or

```
global $card;
$card[] = array  ($suit ." ". $number, hello);
```

Comment: I tried this I think I need to insert new values into the array or something, im not sure when i use the above code it echoes "Array" instead of the suit and card number.

Comment: Now im thinking ny echo needs to be different the one out of the function do i need `global $card;` the link before the `foreach`?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike most sane languages, there is little sense of lexical scope in PHP.  So, your function doesn't recognize variables defined globally.  The easy fix for this is to use `global $card;` inside of your function.